# How to create JSON array using Newtonsoft.Json for this specific structure

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How do I create a JSON array using Newtonsoft.JSON (json.net) from this json string

```
[
  {
    "Cells": {
      "results": [
        {
          "Key": "Title",
          "Value": "hello",
          "ValueType": "Edm.String"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Size",
          "Value": "54549",
          "ValueType": "Edm.Int64"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Path",
          "Value": "http://somesite/a/hello.pptx",
          "ValueType": "Edm.String"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Summary",
          "Value": "Some summary <ddd/> interesting reading <ddd/> nice book <ddd/> ",
          "ValueType": "Edm.String"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Name",
          "Value": "http://somesite",
          "ValueType": "Edm.String"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Cells": {
      "results": [
        {
          "Key": "Title",
          "Value": "hi joe",
          "ValueType": "Edm.String"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Size",
          "Value": "41234",
          "ValueType": "Edm.Int64"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Path",
          "Value": "http://someothersite/interesting/hi.pptx",
          "ValueType": "Edm.String"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Summary",
          "Value": "Some summary <ddd/> interesting reading <ddd/> nice book <ddd/> ",
          "ValueType": "Edm.String"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Name",
          "Value": "http://somesite",
          "ValueType": "Edm.String"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

json2csharp gives me following classes for this structure

```
public class Result
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string ValueType { get; set; }
}

public class Cells
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Cells Cells { get; set; }
}
```

How do I use these classes to create json array?

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION**

this will work

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RootObject ro = new RootObject();
    Cells cs = new Cells();
    cs.results = new List<Result>();

    Result rt = new Result();
    rt.Key = "Title";
    rt.Value = "hello";
    rt.ValueType = "Edm.String";
    cs.results.Add(rt);

    Result rs = new Result();
    rs.Key = "Size";
    rs.Value = "3223";
    rs.ValueType = "Edm.Int64";
    cs.results.Add(rs);

    ro.Cells = cs;

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ro);
}
```

Comment: figured it out, see solution above.  Thanks

Comment: Rather than including the answer in your question, you could [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept the answer so the rest of us can tell your question is resolved.

Comment: Thanks, updated to answer

Answer (score 2):

this will work

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RootObject ro = new RootObject();
    Cells cs = new Cells();
    cs.results = new List<Result>();

    Result rt = new Result();
    rt.Key = "Title";
    rt.Value = "hello";
    rt.ValueType = "Edm.String";
    cs.results.Add(rt);

    Result rs = new Result();
    rs.Key = "Size";
    rs.Value = "3223";
    rs.ValueType = "Edm.Int64";
    cs.results.Add(rs);

    ro.Cells = cs;

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ro);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the function `DeserializeObject<T>`:

```
var json = ""; // string up above in your code
var jObect = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

// Use

var cells = jObject.Cells;
var result1 = cells.results.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to produce json string from my objects, see Update above.

Comment: @pixel Going in the opposite direction is `var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject)`.

Comment: Actually, what I need next is to convert it back to JArray not jsonString :)

Answer (score 0):

Given an example of a POCO below:

```
    public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

This can be achieved by deserializing your JSON string show below:

```
    string json = @"{
   'Email': 'james@example.com',
   'Active': true,
   'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
   'Roles': [
     'User',
     'Admin'
   ]
 }";

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
```

Reference Newtonsoft's documentation below:
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Comment: Thanks, I dont want to use json string.  I am providing json string above just to show the structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the string representation of an object, especially a json object, the most relevant is .ToString ().
But, it could fail for other reasons ...